# How to receive a set from Spring Data JPA NativeQuery? [results in NotReadablePropertyException]

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

First off: I am using `Spring-Boot Data JPA` with Java 8.

I have a table in my database where my entity is defined like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMHOURS")
public class ItemHoursEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "YEAR", nullable = false)
    private String year;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATE", nullable = false)
    private TypeEnum type;

    @Column(name = "HOURVALUE", nullable = false)
    private int hourValue = 0;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
    private MyItem item;
//.. some more columns, getters, setters...
}
```

Now I got the following select returning this structure:

```
-----------------------
| YEAR | Value | Type |
-----------------------

@Query(value = "Select year as year, sum(hourvalue) as value, state as type from ITEMHOURS h where item_id = :item_id group by h.year, h.state", nativeQuery = true)
    public Optional<Collection<TotalValuesProjection>> getYearTotalsForStateByItem(@Param("item_id") int item_id);
```

It works fine in my `MySQL Workbench`. For the result, I heard that I should achieve to grab the result different from the default `ItemHoursEntity` by using a projection, so I tried to create the following:

```
@Projection(types = { ItemHoursEntity.class })
public interface TotalValuesProjection {
    public String getYear();
    public int getValue();
    public HourTypeEnum getType();
}
```

Now in my `service`-class, I try the following:

```
@Override
public List<ExtendedDataPasser<String, Integer, String>> getTotalAndYearHourValuesForItem(int itemId) {

    Optional<Collection<TotalValuesProjection>> projectionOptional = this.hoursRepository.getYearTotalsForStateByItem(itemId);
    List<ExtendedDataPasser<String, Integer, String>> entityList = new ArrayList<ExtendedDataPasser<String, Integer, String>>();
    projectionOptional.orElseGet(() -> new ArrayList<TotalValuesProjection>()).forEach(entity -> {
        entityList.add(new ExtendedDataPasser<String, Integer, String>(entity.getYear(), entity.getValue(), entity.getType().toString()));
    });
    return entityList;
}
```

Sadly, this results in the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'year' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!
        at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.getPropertyValue(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:58) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.PropertyAccessingMethodInterceptor.invoke(PropertyAccessingMethodInterceptor.java:73) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:64) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.getYear(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Maybe the full screenshot of the error helps:

[image]

This is the exception when I try to access `year`-attribute first this is the error: (pretty much the same, just `year` instead of `hourValue`)

[image]

Did I mess something with the mapping from projection to entity?

Comment: Have you printed the values inside the `Collection<TotalValuesProjection>`? 
It looks like your mapping in the repository is not correct. You are probably receiving a Collection<ArrayList<Object>>.

Comment: It think it's case sensitive.. So you need to change the case in query for column names. make it same as DB or entity. Or change `sum(hourvalue) as value` to `sum(hourvalue) as hourValue` It's not able to map hourvalue data as you're defining it as data in query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
@Query(value = "Select year, sum(hourvalue) as value, state as type from ITEMHOURS h where item_id = :item_id group by h.year, h.state", nativeQuery = true)
    public Optional<Collection<TotalValuesProjection>> getYearTotalsForStateByItem(@Param("item_id") int item_id);
```

if any issue inform!!

Comment: Was a nice idea, but did sadly not work out :( - I think its a problem when accessing, when I try to access attribute `value` first, then the error (as above) is thrown for that attribute instead of year

Comment: is it? Am i missing out something? :D

Comment: try this null check , entityList.add(new ExtendedDataPasser<String, Integer, String>(entity!= null?entity.getYear():"", entity!= null?entity.getValue():0, entity!= null?entity.getType().toString():"")); and run maven clean build

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solid solution but just a thinking out loud. It mostly depends on the DBMS and Hibernate versions, but in some cases such an exception may be occured due to case-sencetivity, so try to add quotes to aliases in the native query and table alias to column names as follow:

```
@Query(value = "Select h.year as \"year\", sum(h.hourValue) as \"value\", h.state as \"type\" from ITEMHOURS h where h.item_id = :item_id group by h.year, h.state", nativeQuery = true)
    public Optional<Collection<TotalValuesProjection>> getYearTotalsForStateByItem(@Param("item_id") int item_id);
```

**UPD** change `hourValue` property according to a Java convention - 'h' must be in the uppercase

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that did not change the outcome :(

Comment: you mean the attribute in my Entity? Or where should I change hourValue?